# Global vs Local algebraic number theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Consider an embedding of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ into $\mathbb C_p$ and $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$ not rational.

Denote by $K/\mathbb Q$ the Galois extension generated by $\alpha$.

One can consider $K$ embedded in $\mathbb C_p$.

Let $\mathfrak p$ be a maximal ideal above $p$ of $O_K$, the ring of integers of $K$ and $x\in O_K$.

Denote by $v_p$ the valuation of $\mathbb C_p$, $v_{\mathfrak P}$ the valuation on $O_K$ associated to $\mathfrak p$ and $G$ the Galois group of $K/\mathbb Q$.

Do we have a relation between $v_{\mathfrak P}(x)$, $v_p(\sigma(x))$ ($\sigma \in G$) and $v_p(x)$?

Comment: Be very careful: there is not just *one* valuation on $\mathcal O_K$ associated to $\mathfrak p$ in general.  For example, when $K = \mathbf Q(i)$ and $p = 5$, there are two primes above $5$ in $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[i]$: $(1+2i)$ and $(1-2i)$. That leads to *two* valuations on $K$ that extend $v_5$ on $\mathbf Q$: $v_{(1+2i)}$ and $v_{(1-2i)}$. Those are absolutely not the same functions on $K^\times$.  For example, $3+4i = (2+i)^2 = -(1-2i)^2$, so $v_{(1+2i)}(3+4i) = 0$ and $v_{(1-2i)}(3+4i) = 2$. But these two valuations are related: $v_{(1-2i)}(\alpha) = v_{(1+2i)}(\overline{\alpha})$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\mathfrak P$ to be $\mathcal O_K \cap \mathfrak P_{\Bbb C_p}$, so the extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ generated by the image of $K$ is $K_\mathfrak P$, the completion of $K$ at $\mathfrak P$.

Then clearly $v_p(x) = v_{\mathfrak P}(x)$ for any $x \in K$.

Now for $\sigma \in G$, if $\sigma(\mathfrak P) = \mathfrak P$, then $v_p(\sigma(x)) = v_p(x)$; but otherwise one can find $x \in \mathfrak P \setminus \sigma(\mathfrak P)$, then $v_p(x) > 0$ while $v_p(\sigma(x)) = 0$, and vice versa, so nothing can be said about the relation.

---

### Appendix

WLOG assume $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer and that $K = \Bbb Q(\alpha)$.

Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$. It is a monic polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

An embedding $K \to \Bbb C_p$ is determined by a root $\alpha'$ of $f$ in $\Bbb C_p$.

Factorize $f = f_1 \cdots f_r \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$ into monic irreducible polynomials, where we arrange the polynomials so that $f_1(\alpha') = 0$.

Let $F/\Bbb Q$ be the subfield generated by the coefficients of $f_1$, so $f_1$ is irreducible in $F[x]$. Note that $F \subset \Bbb Q_p$.

Then $[K:F] = [K_\mathfrak P : \Bbb Q_p] = \deg f_1$.

If $g_{\mathcal O_F \cap \mathfrak P}(K/F) > 1$ then we would have at least two $F$-embeddings $K \to \mathcal C_p$, so we would have $[K_\mathfrak P : \Bbb Q_p] < [K:F]$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $g_{\mathcal O_F \cap \mathfrak P}(K/F) = 1$.

The properties $e_p(F/\Bbb Q) = f_p(F/\Bbb Q) = g_{\mathcal O_F \cap \mathfrak P}(K/F) = 1$ are enough for us to conclude that $F = K^{D_{\mathfrak P}}$, where $D_{\mathfrak P} \le G$ is the [decomposition subgroup](https://www.williamstein.org/papers/ant/html/node51.html) of $\mathfrak P$.

We summarize the behaviour of $p$ here:
$$\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
e_p(F/\Bbb Q) &=& 1 &~~~~~~~~~&
e_p(K/F) &=& e_p(K_\mathfrak P / \Bbb Q_p) \\
f_p(F/\Bbb Q) &=& 1 &&
f_p(K/F) &=& f_p(K_\mathfrak P / \Bbb Q_p) \\
g_p(F/\Bbb Q) &=& [F:\Bbb Q] &&
g_p(K/F) &=& 1 \\
\end{array}$$

This provides an "algorithm": first factorize $(p)$ into product of distinct prime ideals in $F$, then choose one of them, say $\mathfrak p$. This gives rise to a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak P$ in $K$.

Then the extension $K_\mathfrak P / \Bbb Q_p$ can be "modelled" by $(\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak P} / (\mathcal O_F)_{\mathfrak p}$, i.e. by $K/F$ but we focus on the prime $\mathfrak p$, in the sense that the former is the completion of the latter.